# jquery mobile, text is behind listview with count bubble

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I created a listview that has a count bubble and a desription of the item for each li.  The problem is that the text for the description falls behind the count bubble.  Is this a glitch or something I can correct with css?

```
echo '<li><a value="' . $row['product_id'] . '" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"><img src="images/' . $row['product_picture_name'] . '.png">' . '<h3>' . $row['product_name'] . '</h3><p style="white-space:normal">' . $row['product_description'] . '</p><span class="ui-li-count">Price: $' . $row['product_price'] . '</span></a></li>';
```

Thanks, Adam.

Comment: Have you looked at the css z-index property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index

Comment: @Calavoow I dont want the count bubble in front if the text or vice_versa.  If the I could get the text to wrap before it gets to the count bubble, then I think that would solve my problem...maybe I could use the css width property, Ill have to see how that would affect the jquerymobile li.

Comment: @Calavoow Adding the width property did the trick! I added width:90% to the <p> tag, don't know why I was trying to make that more complicated than it was. Thanks for sparking the idea!

Comment: I now understand what you wanted. Good luck. An example might've helped clear up the misunderstanding. Also don't forget to wrap up your question with an answer.

Comment: @Calavoow I would of like to put a jfiddle example, but Im not really familiar on how to, but Im sure that would of made my question a lot clearer!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the width property to the p tag of 90%, and the text will start wrapping before it gets to the count bubble position and it scales with different screens sizes.

```
echo '<li><a value="' . $row['product_id'] . '" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"><img src="images/' . $row['product_picture_name'] . '.png">' . '<h3>' . $row['product_name'] . '</h3><p style="white-space:normal; **width:90%;**">' . $row['product_description'] . '</p><span class="ui-li-count">Price: $' . $row['product_price'] . '</span></a></li>';
```